# How to run this code after for loop

Tags: javascript

When i run this code : `

```
for (var start = 1; start < 10; start++) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        alert('hello');  
    }, 3000 * start);
}
alert('Finish');
```

why the for loop has not finished ,but the code 'alert('Finish')' still run .how to make `alert('Finish')` run after finishing for loop .Thanks .

Comment: The loop has finished. The callback you pass to setTimout aren't executed immediately, that's precisely the point of setTimeout.

Comment: so how to change the for loop and excute the code as my think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically that's what its already doing.

The loop runs (setting the timeouts) and then the "finish" alert fires. What I'm guessing you want is the "finish" to fire after all the timeouts have fired off. Easied way to do that would probably be add the finish to its own timeout (so it runs after that amount of time).

Somthing like:

```
for (var start = 1; start < 10; start++){
    setTimeout(function () { console.log('hello'); }
, 10 * start);}; 

// use final "start" time to set last timeout to fire off its event, after all other timeouts have run
setTimeout(function () { 
    console.log('Finish');
}, 10 * (start+1));
```

note: I changed the timings & used console logs so it runs quicker for testing.

Comment: You actually don't need `start+1`, `start` will already be `10`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
var counter = 1;
for(var i = counter; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        counter++;
        if(counter == 10){
            alert("Finish");
        }
        else
            alert("In process");
    }, 10 * i);
}
```

And see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LVLuj/)

Comment: @YOU i think you can evaluate my answer)) if it works)) thanks

Comment: it seems i only have 1 evaluate ,and i did it  for the previous answer !

Comment: @YOU you can do uprate my answer (up arrow)))

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputations

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a different alternative, using setInterval, which imho is better suited for reapeating tasks:

```
var start = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  console.log('hello ' + start);

  if (++start === 10) {
    console.log('all done');
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 3000);
```

This has the advantage of immediately logging 'all done' after the last iteration.